# JavaScript jQuery addClass() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the addClass and removeClass in the following script:

```
function showDiv(e, f) {
  for (i = 0; i < e; i++) {
    $('div.div' + i).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
    $('li.li' + i).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
  }
  $('div.div' + f).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
}

function showLi(e) {
  for (i = 0; i < e; i++) {
    $('div.div' + i).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
    $('li.li' + i).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
  }
}
```

```
<ul>
  <?php for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) { ?>
  <li class="specialistTab li<?php echo $i?>" onclick="showDiv(10,<?php echo $i;?>)" style="background-image:url('images/specialists/<?php echo $rowC[0][2];?>')"></li>
  <div class="sDescription div<?php echo $i?>">
    <div class="sImage" style="background-image:url('images/specialists/<?php echo $rowC[0][2];?>')"></div>
    <div class="sName">
      <?php echo $rowC[0][1];?>
    </div>
    <div class="closeX" onclick="showLi(<?php echo $i?>)">X</div>
    <div class="sDesc">
      <?php echo $rowC[0][3];?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

The code should hide the div when clicking on the list and hide it when we close on the X.

The script is not working.

Comment: Have you tried debugging in showDiv?

Comment: Why don't you just .hide() or .show() the elements?

Comment: You could just use the `toggle()` jQuery function

Comment: You’re generating invalid HTML – you can not have `div` as a child element of `ul`.

Comment: Code seems more complex than it needs to be

Comment: What does your CSS look like for the classes hide and show?

Comment: reomve th PHP part and add some hard coded HTML `div` and '`li' elements, in this way your question will be more readable

Comment: an `li` with a class of `.li`, a `div` with a class of `.div`. why? the click event is from a child element of an `li`. it know's it's parent, you dont need to increment classnames. Also, adding a hide/show class by itself wont do anything, where is your css. Also, how do you **know** it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Jquery for that, you have to add your php loop.

```
//JS script
$(function() {

    $('.tabs li').on('click', function(e) {
        $(e.target).children('.sDescription').show();
    });

    $('.tabs li .close').on('click', function(e) {
        var $parent = $(e.target).parent();
        $parent.hide();
    });
});

//HTML
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <div class="sDescription">
            <div class="sImage"></div>
            <div class="sName">1</div>
            <div class="close">X</div>
            <div class="sDesc">desc1</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="sDescription">
            <div class="sImage"></div>
            <div class="sName">2</div>
            <div class="close">X</div>
            <div class="sDesc">desc1</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Take a look at this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/pafikerizu/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You code can be simplified greatly, and your PHP corrected so you end up with valid HTML:

```
$(function() {
    $('.closeX').on('click', function() {
        $('.sDescription').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
    });
    $('li.specialistTab').on('click', function() {
        $(this).find('.sDescription').addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
    });
});
```

Or just simply:

```
$(function() {
    $('.closeX').on('click', function() {
        $('.sDescription').hide();
    });
    $('li.specialistTab').on('click', function() {
        $(this).find('.sDescription').show();
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<ul>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) { ?>
    <li class="specialistTab" style="background-image:url('images/specialists/<?php echo $rowC[0][2];?>')">
    <div class="sDescription">
        <div class="sImage" style="background-image:url('images/specialists/<?php echo $rowC[0][2];?>')"></div>
        <div class="sName">
            <?php echo $rowC[0][1];?>
        </div>
        <div class="closeX">X</div>
        <div class="sDesc">
            <?php echo $rowC[0][3];?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: hello peter, it worked partially the div wont hide when we click on the X, the addClass and removeClass are not working when I click it, please help

Comment: What if you replace `.addClass('hide').removeClass('show');` with `.hide();` and `.addClass('show').removeClass('hide');` with `.show();`? Does it work?